# Send emails through ASP.NET application without NetworkCredentials (without senders password)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, model-view-controller

I want to send email through my ASP.Net application without hardcoding NetworkCredentials or senders password. 
For suppose i want to have a query form on my web application where an anonymous user can send email to admin without being logged in on his gmail account.
Can anyone help.
I need to use Razor View and C#
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to enable ASP.NET Impersonation. I highly doubt the SMTP server will allow you to use anonymous credentials though

Comment: Are you seriously asking whether there's a mechanism by which random websites on the internet can send emails from the accounts of anyone who happens to access that site?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, It happens in Node.js and i want the same in C# or.Net